# what is the reason for this error. (Prisma)

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I tried this command to apply db.

```
prisma migrate deploy
```

But it doesn't work.
Below error.

```
Error: P3009

migrate found failed migrations in the target database, new migrations will not be applied. Read more about how to resolve migration issues in a production database: https://pris.ly/d/migrate-resolve
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you take a look at the documentation provided by the error message?

https://pris.ly/d/migrate-resolve

The error is pretty self-descriptive: There was a failed migration in your database. In order to get rid of this error, you have a few options:

1. Mark the migration as rolled back, fix the migration, and try to redeploy it [https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/production-troubleshooting#option-1-mark-the-migration-as-rolled-back-and-re-deploy]

```
prisma migrate resolve --rolled-back "NAME_OF_MIGRATION_TO_ROLLBACK"
```

2. Mark the migration as resolved (ignoring errors) and keep going https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/production-troubleshooting#option-2-manually-complete-migration-and-resolve-as-applied

```
prisma migrate resolve --applied "NAME_OF_MIGRATION_TO_APPLY"
```

3. Completely reset the database, fix the migration, and reapply it